# pandoc mmd_title_block appears not to load

Tags: docx, pandoc, multimarkdown

I am new to pandoc and an attempting to use it to convert some simple mmd files to docx. These mmd files contain a mmd style title block in the following form:

```
Author: Author_name  
Title: Title_name  
Date: Date_name
```

I prefer this style to the pandoc style title blocks, so I would like to keep them in the multimarkdown style. The pandoc documentation indicates that there is an extension that will allow me to use them, but when I attempt to use the extension it has no effect on the output. I have tried many permutations of the command to no avail, but an example looks like this:

```
pandoc -f markdown-pandoc_title_block+mmd_title_block -o test.docx testinput.txt
```

If I convert the title block to use pandoc's style, the output properly converts the title blocks to the correct format in the resulting Word file, so I know the reference file is okay. Also, when I keep the title block in pandoc's style but use the markdown-pandoc_title_block command, it properly ignores the title block, so I know the problem is not in the disabling of pandoc title blocks.

Suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me with pandoc 1.11.1. If you're using 1.10.x, there was a bug with this feature that has now been fixed, so you might just need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to Pandoc 1.11.1 and try running the following command, it should work fine:

```
pandoc -f markdown_mmd -t docx test.md -o test.docx
```

It preserves title, author and date fields.